# Hybrid Mobile App using Icenium

Tags: servicestack, icenium

We are working on a Hybrid Mobile app using Icenium.
How do I start using SeriviceStack to develop backend services? Any direction is highly appreciated.

Thank you
Xyler

Comment: what other help  you need ?  Did you read the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Here from ServiceStack Wiki
[Create your first webservice](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice)

For [self hosting](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting)

Here all the  [ServiceStack Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki)

and the knowledge base in StackOverflow  under the tag [ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicestack)

and the [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/servicestack)

there is also a training   course (with payment)  from

[PluralSight- An MVC4, iOS And Android App With ServiceStack, Xamarin and C#](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Description/building-mvc4-ios-android-apps-servicestack-xamarin-csharp)

I don't know if it is useful.

this is not real answer, only to point you the wiki. 
Others can edit to make it better.